# how would you handle this particular api patch versioning for a web api 2.2 solution?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, versioning, semantic-versioning

Google uses the following API versioning strategy:

- MAJOR version when you make incompatible API changes,
- MINOR version when you add functionality in a backwards-compatible manner,
- PATCH version when you make backwards-compatible bug fixes.

https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/versioning

This type of semantic versioning (https://semver.org/) is recommended for NuGet packages as well. Are you using this type of strategy with Web API 2.2 and if so then how are you configuring your Web API solution to handle this? For example, my controller decorators look like this for v2:

```
[ApiVersion("2.0")]
[ControllerName("User")]
[RoutePrefix("api/v{version:apiVersion}/users")]
```

However, we had a lot of changes between version 1.0 and 2.0 so I simply replicated all of the objects into v2 subdirectories and redirected appropriately from the controller. However, I'm not sure what the best approach would be for an API patch versioning scenario. Can you provide an example for how you would handle the following scenario, assuming a standard layered architecture?:

- A v2 dir structure currently exists for the InsuranceEstimateApi
- The CalulatorRepository().Calculate() method has a bug fix (patch) for a subroutine, so according to semantic versioning a version 2.0.1 should be configured

How would you go about configuring a version 2.0.1 within your Web API 2.2 solution to handle this patch?